# Alternative proof for the comparison theorem for solutions of DEs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I am given the following theorem:

> Given the two following IVPs
>   $$\begin{cases}y' = f(t, y(t))\\y(t_0)=y_0\end{cases},\ \ \begin{cases}z' = g(t, z(t))\\z(t_0)=z_0\end{cases}$$
>   If I have $y_0 \leq z_0$ and $f(t, w) \leq g(t, w)$ for $t \geq t_0$ then $y(t) \leq z(t),\ \forall t > t_0$

And I was trying to prove that theorem when I have strict inequalities, i.e. I am given that $f(t, w) < g(t, w)$ and $y_0 < z_0$.

What I did was assume, by contradiction, that at some point I had $y(t) \geq z(t)$ and took $t_m = \{\min t: y(t) \geq z(t)\}$, for which I have $y(t_m) = z(t_m)$. Then I took

$$x(t) = y(t)-z(t)$$ and noticed that for $t < t_m$ I had $x < 0$ and that for $t = t_m$ I had $x(t) = 0$, hence in a neighborhood to the left of $t_m$ I should have $x' > 0$, but $x' = y'-z' < 0$ given that $f < g$, so it could not be the case that $y(t_m) = z(t_m)$.

Is this proof correct? My textbook also took the same $t_m$ but then proceeded to arrive at a contradiction in a different manner.